# praetorian api crypto (how to access an api?) w/ ruby

Tags: ruby, cryptography, challenge-response

I have no idea how to connect to the  [praetorian api](http://www.praetorian.com/challenges/crypto/index.html), as I have never done any work outside of my own server(s), and am not familiar with how token authentication works etc.

Can someone provide more info as to how I can access these challenges vs the instructions given on the site?

I can get the initial level 0 and its hash to appear but I don't know how to send a post or get to the api itself or if that is even what is being asked. *eg in a very dumbed down "type this in the terminal" or replace this with ___", as I literally don't understand what is being said.

Also I have no idea how to get a token from the server, or if that is something outside of ruby.

Comment: I agree that it is a shame they don't provide a GUI and some ready made examples for that *challenge*.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a really basic way to interact with the API with a UI, try using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). I got to level 4 using this approach. But honestly, if interacting with the API is giving you trouble... you're in for some heavy #crypto #pain. I know Praetorian sets the bar pretty high.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks man postman seems to be really straightforward. I figured it out with the rest-client but i just was not sure if the guess choices were actually going through